# Enumeration in longtable misaligns second column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, enumerate

In the image below, I'm trying to figure out how to horizontally align (a) to be in line with Implications. Effectively, have (a) start where xxx is. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Misalignment]

```
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{12cm}}
    Statement: & These principles of information management apply to all organizations within the enterprise. \\
    Rationale: & The only way we can provide a consistent and measurable level of quality information to decision-makers is if all organizations abide by the principles. \\
    Implications: & xxx
        \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
            \setlength\itemsep{0.5em}
            \item Without this principle, exclusions, favoritism, and inconsistency would rapidly undermine the management of information
            \item Information management initiatives will not begin until they are examined for compliance with the principles
            \item A conflict with a principle will be resolved by changing the framework of the initiative
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{longtable}
```

Comment: `enumerate` always start on a new line. And please always post full but minimal examples that others can just copy and test as is. I know here you are using `enumitem` others might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `enumitem` package is simple:

**Edit:**
if you like to star `enumerate` list where is till to now been word `xxxx` and have it vertical aligned with text in the first column, than you need to vertical move list. For example with inserting it in `minipage˛. One option, how to do this is use` etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}         % <---
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}% <---
{
\setlist[enumerate]{label={(\alph*)}, 
                    align=left, 
                    leftmargin=*, 
                    itemsep=0ex,
                    after=\end{minipage},    % <---
                    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                    }
}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{12cm}}
    Statement:      & These principles of information management apply to all organizations within the enterprise. \\
    Rationale:      & The only way we can provide a consistent and measurable level of quality information to decision-makers is if all organizations abide by the principles. \\
    Implications:   &   \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Without this principle, exclusions, favoritism, and inconsistency would rapidly undermine the management of information
                    \item Information management initiatives will not begin until they are examined for compliance with the principles
                    \item A conflict with a principle will be resolved by changing the framework of the initiative
                        \end{enumerate}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: Thank you - I basically need (a) to be where the xxx is.

Comment: @sduplooy, is this mean, that I should delete xxxx and put enumerate in line with text in the first column? This is not straightforward ;-), but i will correct answer ASAP

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted @Zarko! Thank you for your help!